# Textbook discussing a motivation of Schroedinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, resource-recommendations

I am looking for a high-level introduction textbook to quantum mechanics which discusses a motivation behind the Schroedinger equation as completely as possible.

In many textbooks I looked at the motivation is not very convincing for me: sometimes the equation is stated as it is and claimed that it is consistent with experiments. A particularly mysterious case for me is the Schroedinger equation for an electron in a magnetic field.

Comment: You say that you do not find the argument that "it works" to be a convincing argument for its validity, but the reason many books state it like that is that it *is* a completely valid argument in any empirical field.

As for the electron in the magnetic field, do you mean the Hamiltonian for an electron in a magnetic field? In that case, you might want to look into "minimal coupling".

Comment: @Codename47: I am not quite convinced why the classical Hamiltonian should be replaced by a quantum (operator) version of it.

Comment: There aren't many books which do not simply assert that the procedure is correct. You may, however, enjoy Ballentine's book.